# angular 2 "app" naming convention

Tags: angular

I've been going through some Angular 2 examples and the bulk of the files are put into an "app" directory. For a real implementation, would you rename the "app" directory to something like mycompany.mydivision.myproduct? I think this is the traditional namespace naming convention. Just wanted to make sure I understand the approach recommended by Angular for the naming of the "app" directory.

Comment: could you please look at [john papa style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)